# Installing missing python package in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, package

I have the following headers in Visual Studio 2017

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import socketserver
import struct
from threading import Thread
```

This source code is transferred to my Raspberry Pi Stretch but unable to execute because there are missing files. I managed to fix up until h5py. Now, I am stuck. Where can I find the packages for socketserver, struct and thread?

I tried to do sudo apt-get install socketserver but it is not found. Same with others

Comment: apt packages usually are prefixed with `python-` even if that did work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socketserver`, `struct` and `threading` are all Python standard library modules, so since you're running a Debian based distro there is no need to install any external packages to get them.

However, `socketserver` is a Python 3 module, hence not available in Python 2. Maybe this is the issue you're facing?
Which Python version are you using to run the script?

Pasting error message would be helpful.

Comment: Op said he was on rapsberry pi. So he is most likely on a Debian distro.

Comment: Sorry, that's due to my English. I meant "since", not "in case".

Comment: Thanks, I checked it was on Python 2, I changed it to run script using Python 3 but now finds - No module named 'h5py.'

Comment: That's probably because you've installed h5py for Python 2. Try `apt-get install python3-pip` and then `pip3 install h5py`. You may need to use `sudo` to make it work.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get python3-h5py and look on the following link: http://www.donkeycar.com/faq/how-do-i-manually-install-the-software-on-raspberry-pi